# MySQL PHP fill out an empty array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database in which the size of each service used is being saved. In my table the first column is for `name_service`, the second for `size`. So what i need to do is to put the total size of each service, knowing that lines with the same service name may be repeated!

```
$serviceCounts=array();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $size=$row['size'];
    $service=$row['name_service'];  
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: unclear ? but I did get the exact answers I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$serviceCounts=array();

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $size=$row['size'];
    $service=$row['name_service'];  

    if (isset($serviceCounts[ $service ])) {
        $serviceCounts[$service] += $size;
    } else {
        $serviceCounts[$service] = $size;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this to print out the service name and size:

```
foreach ($serviceCounts as $name=>$size) {
    echo "$name: $size\n";
}
```

Comment: oh hell no, just fix the query! this is completely unnecessary

Comment: @Jon Thanks ! any idea on how to put the results in a graph ?

Comment: @STTLCU I know what you mean, except that I can't do this with a query , I have a special database with at least 144 tables and no keys to do joints, so forming another query with loops will take more time than this.

Comment: you do not need to have keys to make joins, @Falcon

Comment: @Falcon on an web page? Maybe have a look at Google Charts https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Comment: @STTLCU you don't need keys to make joints how so ? JOIN.ON what then ?

Comment: You can join on whatever you want. Sure, joining on an index is faster, but it's not necessary @Falcon

Comment: @STTLCU I have a table called table_reference (it include the name of all other tables, some informations about them , but no key, is that what you mean by index ? give me a concrete example

Comment: @Falcon an example about what? about indexes? If you don't know what an index is, you really should go back studying DB theory a little bit. this isn't the place to discuss about this, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Solution**
Check out @Adder solution.

**PHP Solution**

Before the loop:

```
$services = array();
```

Inside the loop:

```
if(array_key_exists($row['name_service'] , $services))
{
  $services[$row['name_service'] += $row['size'];
}
else
{
  $services[$row['name_service'] = $row['size'];
}
```

You're basically using a new array named `services` and checking in the loop if
this service already set in the array or not.
In case that yes - add to it the new row's size,
otherwise add the service name as a new element and set its size.

Comment: You'd need to obviously remove anything other than alphanumeric characters and underscores from $row['name_service'] to make the variable name valid, but +1

Comment: oh hell no, just fix the query! this is completely unnecessary

Comment: @STTLCU you're right , will add this option.
PhilCross - good point, it's an assumption I made.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I know what you mean, except that I can't do this with a query , I have a special database with at least 144 tables and no keys to do joints, so forming another query with loops will take more time than this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the aggregation mysql functionality:

```
SELECT sum(size) as size, name_service FROM services GROUP BY name_service;
```

Untested, you might have to rename the `sum(size) as sum_size`.

Comment: THIS! this is the answer. Really guys, PHP isn't always the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean something like that?

```
$serviceCounts=array();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
    $size=$row['size'];
    $service=$row['name_service'];  

    if (isset($serviceCounts[$service])) {
        $serviceCounts[$service]+=$size;
    } else {
        $serviceCounts[$service]=$size;
    }

}

print_r($serviceCounts);
```

Comment: oh hell no, just fix the query! this is completely unnecessary